# Webpack Tree Shaking not working when importing from a file that has other imports

Tags: javascript, webpack, tree-shaking

I created this example

module.js

```html
import moment from "moment";

export function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}

export function cube(x) {
    return moment.format(x * x * x);
}
```

main.js

```html
import {square} from "./module";

console.log(square(1));
```

I noticed that it also includes moment library in my bundle although I don't use it in square function..
If I remove the moment import from module.js tree shaking works fine and i only see square in my bundle.

Is this how tree shaking suppose to work? is there a workaround except than splitting my code in different files if I want to use an external library in my module.js file?

Comment: Are you sure you have a production build and side effects set to false?

Comment: Yes side effects false on package,json production webpack 5

Answer (score 3):

Ok I figured it out!
I had to specifically set sideEffects for that module in webpack.config rules..

```
 module: {
    rules: [
        {
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/moment"),
            sideEffects: false
        }
    ]
},
```

Answer (score -1):

`Moment.js` is a fantastic time & date library with lots of great features and utilities. However, if you are working on a performance sensitive web application, it might cause a huge performance overhead because of its complex APIs and large bundle size. Also, it is highly based on OOP APIs, which makes it fail to work with tree-shaking, thus leading to a huge bundle size and performance issues.

If you are not using timezone but only a few simple functions, you can have a look at other alternatives like `dayjs`, `date-fns` which have smaller core and provide very similar APIs.

[image]

Detailed explanation and alternate plan can be found on
https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Momentjs

Comment: I appreciate your response dayjs looks interesting.. but my issue is with tree shaking i only used moment as an example

Thank you :)